# How to delete certain root from xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My '.xml' file looks this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Requestes>
  <Single_Request num="1">
    <numRequest>1</numRequest>
    <IDWork>1</IDWork>
    <NumObject>1</NumObject>
    <lvlPriority>Высокий</lvlPriority>
  </Single_Request>
  <Single_Request num="2">
    <numRequest>2</numRequest>
    <IDWork>2</IDWork>
    <NumObject>2</NumObject>
    <lvlPriority>Средний</lvlPriority>
  </Single_Request>
  <Periodic_Request num="1">
    <numRequest>3</numRequest>
    <IDWork>23</IDWork>
    <pFrequency>23</pFrequency>
    <lvlPriority>Низкий</lvlPriority>
    <time_service>23</time_service>
    <time_last_service>23</time_last_service>
    <relative_time>23</relative_time>
  </Periodic_Request>
</Requestes>
```

So I need to delete `Single_Request` with atribute value equal to `sTxtBlock_numRequest.Text`. I have tried to do it this way:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);

IEnumerable<XElement> sRequest = doc.Root.Descendants("Single_Request").Where(
                                 t => t.Attribute("num").Value =="sTxtBlock_numRequest.Text"); //I'm sure, that problem is here
sRequest.Remove();

doc.Save(FilePath);
```

Unfortunattly, nothing has happanned, don`t know how to solve the problem.

This is why , I am looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing attribute value with string literal `"sTxtBlock_numRequest.Text"`. You should pass value of textbox text instead:

```
doc.Root.Elements("Single_Request") 
   .Where(t => (string)t.Attribute("num") == sTxtBlock_numRequest.Text)
   .Remove();
```

Note - it's better to use `Elements` when you are getting `Single_Request` elements of root, because `Descendants` will search whole tree, instead of looking at direct children only. Also you can call `Remove()` without saving query to local variable.

Comment: Isn't  `.Value` convert Attribute to string?

Comment: @Rocketq `.Value` returns value of attribute. But it also throws exception if attribute not exist in element. Casting to string also returns value of attribute, but it returns `null` if attribute not found.